# Fail2ban does not ban any ip-adresses with vsftpd

Tags: ftp, gentoo, fail2ban

Fail2ban starts okey. It work with my sshd filter and bans IP-adresses as it should. But with vsftpd it does not register failed logins when I run:

```
fail2ban-client status vsftpd
```

I have tried both the auth.log and vsftpd.log. The file path is changed from what I really have for security reasons and are not really /path/to/thelog.log

`vsftpd.log`:

```
Status for the jail: vsftpd
|- filter
|  |- File list:    /path/to/vsftpd.log 
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  `- Total failed: 0
`- action
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |  `- IP list:   
   `- Total banned: 0
```

`auth.log`:

```
Status for the jail: vsftpd
|- filter
|  |- File list:    /path/to/auth.log 
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  `- Total failed: 0
`- action
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |  `- IP list:   
   `- Total banned: 0
```

But with fail2ban-regex it catches the failed logins.

`vsftpd.log`:

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/vsftpd.conf
Use         log file : /path/to/vsftpd.log


Results
=======

Failregex: 16 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   2) [16] ^ \[pid \d+\] \[.+\] FAIL LOGIN: Client "<HOST>"\s*$
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [806] WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second Year
`-

Lines: 806 lines, 0 ignored, 16 matched, 790 missed
Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 790 lines
```

`auth.log`:

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/vsftpd.conf
Use         log file : /path/to/auth.log


Results
=======

Failregex: 16 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [16] ^\s*(<[^.]+\.[^.]+>)?\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[ *\d+\.\d+\])?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?vsftpd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?vsftpd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:?)?\s(?:\[ID \d+ \S+\])?\s*\(?pam_unix(?:\(\S+\))?\)?:?\s+authentication failure; logname=\S* uid=\S* euid=\S* tty=(ftp)? ruser=\S* rhost=<HOST>(?:\s+user=.*)?\s*$
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [9174] MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 9174 lines, 0 ignored, 16 matched, 9158 missed
Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 9158 lines
```

I've tested by failing to login with the right password (logging in the wrong password  that is :) ) and with `fail2ban-regex` the number keeps rising but the status for the jail is still 0 and three failed logins do not trigger a ban.

`jail.local`:

```
[vsftpd]
enable     = true
filter     = vsftpd
action     = iptables-multiport[name=vsftpd, port="20, 21, 10204, 10205"]
logpath    = /path/to/auth.log
bantime   = 60
maxretry   = 3
```

bantime 60 sec is only during testing.

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: What's your `findtime` ?

Comment: Not sure. Is that a setting or test?

Comment: It's a setting in your `jail.conf` file. Usually people forget this and the gap between attemps is smaller than the find time so noone gets banned.

Comment: What is a good findtime? Seems like 600 seconds is default according to fail2ban manual.

Comment: There's no rule of thumb, it depends on what you see in your logs and your banning policy.

Answer (score 4):

`vsftpd.log` deny log looks like:

```
Wed Jun 29 14:57:37 2016 [pid 2517] [username] FTP response: Client "::ffff:192.168.0.100", "530 Permission denied."
```

and the default failregex WHICH isn't working in fail2ban config file located "`/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/vsftpd.conf`" looks like

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s%(__pam_re)s\s+authentication failure; logname=\S* uid=\S* euid=\S* tty=(ftp)? ruser=\S* rhost=<HOST>(?:\s+user=.*)?\s*$
            ^ \[pid \d+\] \[.+\] FAIL LOGIN: Client "<HOST>"\s*$
```

So **you need to change failregex** to the following to get it working with vsftpd

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s%(__pam_re)s\s+Permission denied; logname=\S* uid=\S* euid=\S* tty=(ftp)? ruser=\S* rhost=<HOST>(?:\s+user=.*)?\s*$
            ^ \[pid \d+\] \[.+\]\s+FTP response: Client "::ffff:<HOST>",\s*"530 Permission denied\."\s*$
```

Checked on Ubuntu with vsftpd: version 3.0.3

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hadn't the "::ffff:" in front of the IP. So "<HOST>" worked for me. Also added the original regex after this new one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in your `jail.local`. It's `enabled = true` not `enable`.

You should check your `fail2ban.log` that contains a line like:

```
INFO    Jail 'vsftpd' started
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are your log files stored?

Are they in /scripts/logs/vsftpd.log and /scripts/logs/auth.log? That is where the fail2ban daemon is looking for them as per your jail.local.

Because in your fail2ban-regex output pastes, it is saying it is using /path/to/vsftpd.log and /path/to/auth.log.

Did you just cut out the /scripts/logs/ from the fail2ban-regex outputs and paste in the /path/to/ placeholders? Or are your logs actually in /path/to/?

Comment: I was trying to just use placeholders to not show the actual path but failed on jail.local. They are in scripts/logs folder.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured, but I had to be sure -- maybe you had copy/pasted the vsftpd.conf from somewhere and didn't edit the path.

Answer (score -1):

```
dual_log_enable=YES
```

This setting enable DNS and IP search