# fail2ban with vsftpd explicit sftp

Tags: fail2ban, vsftpd, brute-force-attacks

The *fail2ban vsftpd* default config doesn't take care of blocking brute force requests when *tls* is enabled on *vsftpd*.
At the moment the *vsftpd* log only shows the below lines which don't match the regex. Does anyone have a good regex to take care of banning?

```
Fri Mar  3 19:56:16 2017 [pid 19866] CONNECT: Client "39.162.209.108"
Fri Mar  3 19:56:17 2017 [pid 19868] CONNECT: Client "39.162.209.108"
```

Comment: Maybe this will get you started on a suiting regex:
http://serverfault.com/questions/641442/fail2ban-does-not-ban-any-ip-adresses-with-vsftpd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail2ban does not ban any ip-adresses with vsftpd](http://serverfault.com/questions/641442/fail2ban-does-not-ban-any-ip-adresses-with-vsftpd)

Answer (score 0):

Got it. When implicit FTP is used the vsftpd logs don't display failures as they normally do if users attempt to login without SSL. I had to add the below to the vsftpd config file file.

```
log_ftp_protocol=YES
```

Then I added the below to fail2ban's filter for vsftpd.

```
Client "<HOST>", "530 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption."
Client "<HOST>", "530 Anonymous sessions must use encryption."
```

This will catch users who aren't aware the encryption is needed but for us it is far more likely to catch the constant brute force traffic.